# looking for method to invert color of text when placed over black & white objects

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, watermark

I have a black and white image with various shapes.
I want to place text on the image that is larger than some of the black and white shapes.  To keep the text readable and not blank-out some sections of a letter, I am hoping a method exists in Python Pillow that allows text to be positioned over the image and invert the color of each text pixel (from what already exists in the position on the base image).

As in the below image.

Note, I have already done this by looking at each pixel and inverting.  However, that is extremely slow. I am hoping a known method is faster.

Again, all I am looking for is a method in PIL that can create the effect below without doing pixel-by pixel adjustments. I'm just not finding the method by I somehow remember seeing a that this is possible in PIL. Thanks.

Here is the effect I am trying to achieve when placing the word "text" on an image containing a black rectangle.

[image]

Comment: please provide your code so others can see if they could make it better ? `slow` is opaque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could think of xnor-ing between the two images. But first I assume that you already have a `background` and a `text` image, both are color images.  Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
# Change both images to binary (black-white) images
bg = Image.open("background.png") # open colour image
bg = bg.convert('1')
text = Image.open("text.png") # open colour image
text = text.convert('1')
# Xnor_image = invert(XOR(text, background))
bg = ImageChops.logical_xor(bg,text)
bg = ImageChops.invert(bg)

bg.save('res.png')
```

`background.png`
[image]
`text.png`
[image]
`result.png`
[image]

Comment: I love it!  Thank you. I'll let you know if it works the same way for me.

Comment: glad you find it helpful :)

Comment: I already have 1-bit images so I really only needed your ImageChop xor and invert commands.  I look forward to trying it on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

- you propably have to create two images,
- then blend them using the blend mode "difference".
- top image: your text
- bottom image: any other image
- pillow does not yet seem to support blend-modes. try this extension
- instead:  https://pythonhosted.org/blend_modes/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).